# How to make a bone location change another bone rotation?

Tags: bones

[image]

[image]

Hi , can someone show me the correct way  to set up  the bones so when lower bone moves forward ,the upper bone rotate backward? And when the lower bone moves backward the upper bone rotate forward? ( Both bone are on a single armature )

No one could foind the solution so far on reddit and other blender forums.

Answer (score 2):

Give a ***Transformation*** constraint to the bone that is supposed to rotate, enable *Extrapolation*, click on *Map From > Location* (with a *Min* and *Max* values on the axis you want), and *Map To > Rotation*. For the axis rotation of the constrained object, determine what is the axis source of its rotation (for me its rotation on Y will be determined by the other bone X location, so I need to set the *Y Source Axis* to X), and choose the latitude in degrees. As you have enabled extrapolation it will extrapolate the movement according to the ratio you've set:

[image]

[image]

Also you can constrain the location and rotation of your controller object.

Comment: It seem i have tons tons of testing to do , because no matter what settings i use it barely does anything( it makes my bone rotate ,but  just a little , and strangely enough , most of axis i use don't do anything at all )

Comment: note that I haven't used the same axis as you, maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: The other axis do not work , i am setting them up the way i understand from the example to  , but upper bone only react to one axis no matter what values i use in other axis.

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: ( It's currently mapped to X axe   , when i delete X axe and try setting up other axe , it just wont do anything ) https://pasteall.org/blend/1520b642007b4491996e01ff08e50b5e

Comment: The X rotation of your vertical bone will depend on the Y location of your horizontal bone, so you need to choose X Source Axis > Y, and -20/+20°, then in Map From choose something like Y > -1/+1

Comment: the bone still isn't doing anything no matter what setting i use in all axis/location/rotation .

Comment: it works here, here is your file modified: https://pasteall.org/blend/e84bee6335384205be3c6a25713f9cbc

Comment: How come you have greyed out areas and i don't (EX: X mIn / Max) ? It does not seem like you locked any axis

Comment: it's deactivated as X lotation is not selected in any of the rotation sources in the Map To section, but if you select Y Source > X for example it will be displayed

Comment: Since it doesn't worked even with copying the sames values , i just found a tutorial on how to set up Bone Drivers , the stuff to write in drivers is annoying but it's working well so far!

Comment: yes Drivers is the other solution, you should easily find why the constraint doesn't work though, you can share your file again if you want